# Large iteration loops in CUDA kernels causes memory error

Tags: cuda

I am trying to write a CUDA kernel where each thread executes a separate iterative algorithm.  Sort of like many independent Newton-Raphson solves.  The problem is that after a certain number of iterations, something goes wrong.  Googling around indicates it may be a segmentation fault, but I do not know how to correct this.  I wrote some toy code that reproduces the error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 3

__device__ void devFunc(float4 *in, float4 *out){

    out[0] = in[0];

    //Placeholder useless computations
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
        out[0].w = out[0].w + 1.0;
        out[0].x = out[0].w + 1.0;
        out[0].y = out[0].w + 1.0;
        out[0].z = out[0].w + 1.0;
        out[0].w = out[0].w - 1.0;
        out[0].x = out[0].w - 1.0;
        out[0].y = out[0].w - 1.0;
        out[0].z = out[0].w - 1.0;
    }

    out[0].w = 26.0;
    out[0].x = 26.0;
    out[0].y = 26.0;
    out[0].z = 26.0;
}


__global__ void testKernel(float4 *vects){

    const int i = blockIdx.x;

    //Iterative algorithm, fails for 1000 iterations
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j){
        devFunc(&vects[i], &vects[i]);
    }

}


int main(){

    float4 vects[N];

    //Preprare original data
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        vects[i].w = 5.0;
        vects[i].x = 5.0;
        vects[i].y = 5.0;
        vects[i].z = 5.0;
    }

    //Print original data
    std::cout << "Original data:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        std::cout << vects[i].w 
            << "\t" << vects[i].x 
            << "\t" << vects[i].y 
            << "\t" << vects[i].z 
            << "\t" << std::endl;
    }

    cudaError_t stat = cudaSuccess;

    float4 *d_vects;
    stat = cudaMalloc(&d_vects, sizeof(float4)*N);
    assert(stat == cudaSuccess);
    stat = cudaMemcpy(d_vects, vects, sizeof(float4)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    assert(stat == cudaSuccess);

    testKernel<<<N, 1>>>(d_vects);

    stat = cudaMemcpy(vects, d_vects, sizeof(float4)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    assert(stat == cudaSuccess);
    stat = cudaFree(d_vects);
    assert(stat == cudaSuccess);

    //Print processed data
    std::cout << "Processed data:" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        std::cout << vects[i].w
            << "\t" << vects[i].x
            << "\t" << vects[i].y
            << "\t" << vects[i].z
            << "\t" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

The toy code changes a few vectors of 5's into vectors of 26's in a very inefficient manner, but more importantly reproduces the error.  So when I run the for loop in the `__global__` kernel for 1000 iterations, this triggers an error code 4 on my `cudaMemcpy` of `d_vects` back to the host.  If I downgrade the iterations to 100, everything will work fine.  I also tried a version of the above code where the `__device__` function takes and returns `float4` instead of pointers... same error.

One theory I had was that maybe my data structures were not "naturally aligned" according to the Size and Alignment Requirement of the CUDA programming guide:

> "Reading non-naturally aligned 8-byte or 16-byte words produces incorrect results (off by a few words), so special care must be taken to maintain alignment of the starting address of any value or array of values of these types." [see here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses)

But that can't be the problem because I am using CUDA's `float4` which the programming guide says fills the requirements.  My hardware's compute capability is 5.2.

So my question is what is causing this error and how can it be corrected?  Thank you.

Some other things I've tried:

• Adjusting the 3rd argument of the execution configuration `<<<Dg, Db, Ns, S>>>`, i.e. the number of bytes in shared memory that is dynamically allocated

• Adjusting the [heap memory allocation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#heap-memory-allocation)

It is also useful to note that the amount of computation in the "`//Placeholder useless computations`" above changes the number of iterations that may be performed before the memcpy error arises.  For example, if I replaced the placeholder with something closer to a Newton iteration, the error appears after only 8 iterations.

Thank you.

Comment: are you running this code on a display gpu?

Comment: It's my laptop's GPU: GeForce GTX 970M

Comment: you are hitting a display  driver timeout limit. when your code runs for too long on a display device, the driver will terminate it

Comment: Yup, you are right.  Thanks for marking this as a duplicate.  You pointed me in the right direction cause I was looking in the wrong places ...for 2 days :-(